# Scheduler going idle under multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, scheduler

I'm running Python 3.3.2, Win7/Pro, 64-bit and have some code in which I'm trying to run a scheduler in its own thread.   It appears that when the scheduler empties its working queue, it goes idle and does not resume even when a new entry is added to the queue.   It's not completely obvious to me from the docs that it is supposed to resume, but I would not expect user code (running in a thread outside the control of the scheduler) to have to worry about the possibility of that the scheduler has "finished".   I suspect there is something I'm not understanding and/or that I'm misusing it somehow, but I don't know where.

In the example below, I solved the problem by replacing the scheduler's enter method with my own which checks the queue length and if it is zero, enters the request and then calls the scheduler's run method again.  This does seem to work, but definitely feels wrong.   Is there something I'm missing?

```
class A(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.schedControl = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep)
        self.senter = self.schedControl.enter
        self.schedControl.enter = self.enter
    def print_time(self, a=''):
        """Print current time and optional message."""
        tmx = time.time()
        tms = time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime(tmx))
        print("{0}:  {1}".format(tms, a))
    def run(self):
        #for call by thread's start method
        self.schedControl.run()

    def enter(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tmp = False
        if len([x for x in self.schedControl.queue]) == 0:
            tmp = True
        self.senter(*args, **kwargs)
        if tmp:
            print("Restart")
            self.schedControl.run()

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.scheduler = A()
        self.itemCount = 0
        self.scheduler.schedControl.enter(1, 1, self.scheduler.print_time, argument=('Starting Scheduler',))
        self.scheduler.start()

    def newItem(self):
        self.scheduler.schedControl.enter(1, 1, self.scheduler.print_time, argument=('New Item: {0}'.format(self.itemCount),))
        self.itemCount += 1
foo = B()
foo.newItem()
time.sleep(5)
foo.newItem()
time.sleep(5)
foo.newItem()
time.sleep(5)
foo.newItem()
time.sleep(5)
foo.newItem()
print("Going to sleep")
time.sleep(100)
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Where is the code for `self.senter()`? I assume that that is where you actually take something off the queue. Need to see it to understand what is actually happening.

Comment: self.senter is the capture (see __init__) of the enter method of the Python Scheduler.

Comment: The docs for `sched` indicate that it is not thread-safe until Python 3.3. I assume you are at that level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html), `sched` will run all scheduled events with `run()`. The text is a little obscure, but I believe that `run()` returns once all scheduled events are complete. If that is the case you will need to add more events and call `run()` again, and given your reported results that seems to be what is happening.

Comment: I agree that the docs are not inconsistent with that reading, but I would have strongly expected it to be mentioned in the run() docs and to have some mechanism simpler than checking the queue yourself for causing it.   Maybe the code is just young...

Comment: At least they provide the `isEmpty()` method to do it.